# Setting classpath in windows

Tags: java, classpath, cmd

I setup classpath in enviroment variables i set a user variable named classpath with value= .;C:\Users\Borut\Downloads\httpcomponents-client-4.1.2-bin\lib

the directory is full of .jar files. yet still when i run a program through cmd it reports an error  that the package from the class does not exist.

Comment: You need to name the jar files themselved on the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, you've needed to include the jar files themselves, not the directory they're in, on the `CLASSPATH`. In recent JREs, you can use a wildcard (i.e., a path ending in `/*`) to indicate all the jars in a directory. But if you indicate only a directory, then that directory is searched for class files and packages only; jar files are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either (a) explicitly list the jar files, or (b) use a wildcard classpath (1.6+).